# How to get the up arrow key to return the last command in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

You know how in MATLAB, when you press on up arrow key you get the last command? Well I somehow changed that in the Preferences and now instead of returning the last commands, it navigates up in the prompt window. The thing is, I don't remember what I did, and I can't find the place where I change it back.
So my question is - how do I turn it back so I get the last commands?
I'm using the 7.7.0 version. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

OK, found it. It's on File-> Preferences-> Command Window-> Accessibility-> Arrow keys navigate instead of recalling history.