# How to make "up"key complete the already typed command from history, not pick any that contains the already typed part?

Tags: matlab

Until recently, when I typed

```
x=1;
2*x;
x
```

into the command window (without pressing enter after x) and pressed the arrow up key, the line was completed with the last command in the history that started with the already typed part, here the first line. Recently, the behavior changed to replacing it with the last command that contains the already typed part, i.e. the second line in the example, without me knowingly changing any setting.

How do I get the old behaviour back? In "Perferences->Keyboard->Shortcuts" (as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981038/how-to-get-the-up-arrow-key-to-return-the-last-command-in-matlab)) the up key is associated with "Cursor up" and "Previous History Command", but the description of the latter is ambiguous regarding the expected behaviour when something is already typed into the command line.

Comment: "unitl recently". When did that change? Do you have a newer/older version of Matlab now? What did you have before?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I did not knowingly change any setting, much less the installed version of MATLAB (which is R2014a). However, I sometimes find myself typing something, believing it to appear in the command window when the active window/tab is actually another one, so if there is a way to change this behaviour via a keyboard shortcut, I may have unfortunately typed it.

Comment: I've had the same experience since switching to R2014a on windows 8.1 and didn't have that issue with the R2013 (a I think) on a windows 7 before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that the command history window is docked (If you have a floating window every time you press up then it is not docked. There is a drop-down menu  - little circle with a triangle inside. Open the menu and select "Dock").

Once\if the window is docked, open the menu again and make sure that "Match Beginning" is selected and not "Match Anywhere".

Comment: Thank you! When the search box is open, there are even buttons for this behaviour. And it can indeed be (de-)activated by keyboard shortcut, so maybe I pressed Ctrl+Shift+A accidentally...